# How to switch to another vim window and specify cursor location

Tags: vim

I have two vim windows, and I want to go to another window according to a function.

I hope to specify the cursor location in my function. The code is

```
call feedkeys("\<C-W>W<CR>")
call cursor(10,10)
```

However, the `cursor` function is still bound to original window. How to let `cursor` know I have switched to new window?

Answer (score 3):

`feedkeys()` just adds (virtual) keystrokes to the input queue, and that will only be processed once your Vim function returns. That's why your cursor placement is executed *before* the switch in windows.

In general, avoid `feedkeys()` unless you really need it! (Those situations are few.) To execute a normal mode command, use `:normal!` instead. For window commands, there's even a special `:wincmd` (as you've discovered).

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution:

```
wincmd w
call cursor(10,10)
```